# Copying using vba

Tags: excel, vba

Hi Im new to VBA I have a code here that should copy a column from workbook A to Workbook B. There seems to be an error. Pls help

Here is my code

```
Sub try()

Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook

Set x = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\alfred.anton.s.mateo\Documents\TaskTracker_2\TaskTracker_trial\TASK_TRACKERV5 - A")
Set y = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\alfred.anton.s.mateo\Documents\Certificate\Consolidate")


'Transfer values from x to y
y.Sheets("STORES").Range("J7").Value = x.Sheets("WeekSummary").Range("J7:J45")
x.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Your two ranges are not of the same size. try making both of them `Range("J7:J45")`

Answer (score 1):

```
x.Sheets("WeekSummary").Range("J7:J45").Copy
y.Sheets("STORES").Range("J7").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, operation:=xlNone
x.Close
```